# Move my ether from own Mist-wallet to online wallet

Tags: wallet-transfer

Trying to get my ether out but no transfer works. Sync says 3 month 0% since days.

Is there any possibility to use any online wallet instead? And if yes, how to import my ether other than transfer?

OS: win7
latest version ethereum wallet

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using Parity if you want a local wallet https://ethcore.io/parity.html , recommendation is based solely on its sync speed.

> is there any possibility to use any online wallet instead?

Yes there is. You could use something like https://www.myetherwallet.com/ .

> and if yes how to import my ether other than transfer?

You can just import your current wallet's private key.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#send-transaction) to access your ethers either via Keystore file or your Private key. I am sure there must be many other online wallets providing the same or maybe better functionality. 
You can also look at [Jaxx Wallet](https://jaxx.io/). I have not used it personally but this wallet also provides the same functionality.

PS: Please choose third party wallets at your own risk. Some of them are still in beta phase so it is not recommended for keeping a large amount of ethers.